# How to securely host multiple CMS on the same domain?

Tags: wordpress, security, magento, content-management-system

We have a WordPress Blog and a Magento store currently hosted on different subdomains. We are planning to move them to the same main domain, so the URL's will look like this:

```
domain.com <--- Magento Store
domain.com/blog/ <--- WordPress Blog
```

Our main concern is the security of the e-commerce store. We don't feel safe hosting both CMS in the same document root.

Are there some best practices for how to securely host multiple CMS on the same domain? We have thought about moving part of the code outside of the doc root or setting different user permissions for each CMS. Appreciate your ideas!

Comment: I was told that the best way to restrict access between folders on the same virtual host is by setting up multiple PHP-FPM process pools in different chroot environments. If anyone knows easier way, please do share.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to post an update and share how we end up resolving this project on our server.

1. We have created a separate virtual host for the blog (e.g. blog.example.com). This virtual host is hosted on the local IP with a specific internal port and is not visible outside.
2. The web folder of the blog had a separate restricted Unix user:group that has access only to the blog web folder
3. We used separate MySQL user for the Blog with permissions for the Blog database only
4. Lastly, we've created a proxy redirect on example.com that pointed to the separate virtual host (example.com/blog => blog.example.com)
5. blog.example.com uses its own php-fpm pool to process PHP scripts.